# How can I make my if statement evaluate correctly?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm creating a stopwatch that stops after hearing a clap. My first function creates a `flag` variable and calls another. When a loud noise is heard, the `flag` changes from `false` to `true` and should return `true` to the caller function. A conditional `if` statement should stop the stopwatch. However, my stopwatch does not stop after returning true.

```
function callStopwatch() {
    var watch = new Stopwatch(timer);
    watch.start();
    var flag = false;
    draw(flag);
    if(flag == true){
        watch.stop();
    }
}

function draw() {
    var vol = mic.getLevel();
    if(vol > 0.2){
        console.log("true"); //created to check whether sound detection is working
        flag = true;
        return flag;
    }
}
```

`console.log` returns `true` to the console when a clap is heard. Therefore, the flag should become `true` and return as such and evaluate properly in the caller function's `if` statement. What could I be doing incorrectly? My guess would be not understanding function scope properly.

Comment: Javascript is `Async`, it won't wait for `draw()` to return correct flag, you can try [callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) instead!

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to update your flag variable in callStopwatch() after calling function draw.

```
 function callStopwatch() {
 var watch = new Stopwatch(timer);
 watch.start();
 var flag = false;
 flag = draw(flag); // update flag here
 if(flag == true){
    watch.stop();
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since javascript is `async`, it won't wait for `draw()` to return correct value, it will execute your code `async`, you can try something like this which mentioned under [callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function).

```
draw(flag, function(_flag) {
    if (_flag == true) {
      //to stop watch
      console.log("its true");
    } else {
      console.log("it's false")
    }
  });
```

Furthermore, your `draw()` should look something like this.

```
function draw(flag, callback) {
  var vol = 0.1; // approx value try changing it to 0.3 will return true based on condition
  if (vol > 0.2) {
    flag = true;
  }
  callback(flag);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First issue is that you are not returning flag value from `draw()`. You need to remember that flag property has local scope, so inside of `draw()` function you have a new variable. That is why changing `flag` property inside `draw()` function does not affect `flag` property in `callStopwatch`

```
function callStopwatch() {
    var watch = new Stopwatch(timer);
    watch.start();
    if(draw()){
        watch.stop();
    }
}

function draw() {
    let flag = false;
    var vol = mic.getLevel();
    if(vol > 0.2){
        console.log("true"); //created to check whether sound detection is working
        flag = true;
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Second approach would be to pass a callback to the draw function.

```
function callStopwatch() {
    var watch = new Stopwatch(timer);
    watch.start();
    draw(function() {watch.stop();});
}

function draw(onCondition) {
    var vol = mic.getLevel();
    if(vol > 0.2){
        console.log("true"); //created to check whether sound detection is working
        onCondition()
    }
}
```

Now you don't need the flag property at all.

Comment: I'm trying to use your second approach since the first didn't work for me. I might be missing something very obvious, but my console threw up a message saying ```Uncaught TypeError: onCondition is not a function```. I appended a semicolon after ```onCondition()``` after the ```console.log``` line just to make sure. What do you mean by this?

Comment: I have updated my answer. ()=> {} is a shorter version of calling an anonymous function.